# SQL Server : Multiple rows XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, ssis, etl

I extracted xml file and move it SQL Server.
It now looked like this.

[image]

Now I'm trying to convert it to XML data type.

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML

SELECT @XML = convert(xml,[Column 0],2) FROM TestExtract
```

But Im getting this error

> XML parsing: line 1, character 43, unable to switch the encoding

Maybe I should put all rows into one? then convert it?
   Please advise for any options.

Thanks!

Comment: First of all, your data should be contained in a single cell. Yes.

Comment: how can I do it? I have 400k rows

Comment: You can create a table with an XML typed column, and index it, to get good performance with a large XML.
https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/getting-started-with-xml-indexes/

Comment: How do you get the data into your DB?

Comment: I used SSIS, flat file as a source and ole db(SQL server) as destination

Comment: Try to read the entire file as a single value with the Flat File source, I'm pretty sure it's possible.

Comment: @VillapandoCedric why you didn't used the XML source instead of Flat File source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I used SSIS, flat file as a source and ole db(SQL server) as destination

### Why you haven't imported the XML using XML Source instead of Flat File source?

If the XML file is well structured then you can use an XML Source to import data into SQL Server, there are many example found online:

- [Importing XML documents using SQL Server Integration Services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3141/importing-xml-documents-using-sql-server-integration-services/)
- [Extract Data by Using the XML Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/extract-data-by-using-the-xml-source?view=sql-server-2017)
- [XML Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/xml-source?view=sql-server-2017)

### Other approach

You can directly read the XML file from SQL Server using ad hoc queries (OPENROWSET):

- [Importing and Processing data from XML files into SQL Server tables](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2899/importing-and-processing-data-from-xml-files-into-sql-server-tables/)

### Current situation

First of all combine all rows into one value, then try to convert the value.

```
DECLARE @strXML VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @XML AS XML
SET @strXML = ''

SELECT @strXML = @strXML + [Column 0] FROM Testextract
//SELECT @strXML = @strXML + [Column 0] + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) FROM Testextract    

SET @XML = convert(xml,@strXML,2)
```